# The odd ones out

Tags: odd-one-out

***I would like you to find the odd ones out of each of the sets.  Get them written down and then follow the next instruction.***


1) Dodo, Quagga, Pelican
2) Tantalum, Livermorium, Molybdenum
3) Trumpet, Tuba, Zither
4) Unicorn, Horse, Zebra, Mule, Donkey
5) Nickel, Penny, Dime, Dollar, Cent
6) Sonic, Deafening, Visions, Earache, Sound
7) Below, Ontop, Beneath, Under
8) Lemonade, Coca-Cola, Fanta, Lilt, Tea
9) Happiness, Anger, Gratefullness, Eager
***The next thig that you have to do is take the starting letters of your answers and then give me your final answer.***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The odd ones out are

> 1) Dodo, Quagga, **Pelican** (others are extinct)
>  2) Tantalum, **Livermorium**, Molybdenum (only one that's synthetic)
>  3) Trumpet, Tuba, **Zither** (others are wind instruments)
>  4) **Unicorn**, Horse, Zebra, Mule, Donkey (others are real animals)
>  5) Nickel, **Penny**, Dime, Dollar, Cent (others are official names of US coins)
>  6) Sonic, Deafening, **Visions**, Earache, Sound (others relate to hearing)
>  7) Below, **Ontop**, Beneath, Under (others mean "below")
>  8) Lemonade, Coca-Cola, Fanta, Lilt, **Tea** (others are cold drinks)
>  9) Happiness, Anger, Gratefullness, **Eager** (others are nouns)

The first letters make up the phrase...

> Plz upvote :)

Comment: You got them all correct. BTW, it is penny because the rest is part of American currency.

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I thought about that, but I believe a US one-cent coin is called a penny?

Comment: @jafe See the 2nd paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_(United_States_coin)).

Comment: @WAF Ok, so the others are actual official names of the coins. Edited that in :)

Comment: How is [lemonade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemonade) a trademark?

Comment: @Chowzen Ahh of course, it's not. Fixing...

Comment: I live in the US "South." Tea is a cold drink. :)